# Laravel 4 and Sentry 2 ACL structure and access control levels

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am developing a site using laravel 4, and trying to implement my ACL using Sentry 2. I need help on how to structure the following:

I have the following permissions for role HR:

```
Staffs|View staff details
Staffs|Register new staff
Staffs|Edit staff details
Staffs|Delete staff details
```

Corresponding to the following routes:

```
//get route to staffs landing page
Route::get('staffs/view-staffs', 'UsersController@getManageStaffs'); 

//post routes
Route::post('staffs/add-staff', 'UsersController@postAddStaff');
Route::post('staffs/update-staff', 'UsersController@postUpdateStaff');
Route::post('staffs/delete-staff', 'UsersController@postDeleteStaff');
```

I need access control for the following:

1. link on my menu for view-staffs: if all staff permission are disabled, disable link. This is how i am doing it:

   ```
   if($user->hasAnyAccess(array('Staffs|View staff details', 'Staffs|Register new staff', 'Staffs|Edit staff details', 'Staffs|Delete staff details')))
   {
       //display menu link
   }
   ```
2. my routes: if all staff permissions are disabled, disable all routes that fall under "staffs/"

   ```
   //For this, i have no idea how to restrict routes based on my permissions
   //But i don't want to do it like i did in (1) within my controllers
   ```
3. disable action buttons that corresbond to a disabled permission

   ```
   //same as no (1)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

In app/filters.php, create a filter as follows.

```
Route::filter('permissions', function()
{
    $name = Route::current()->getName();
    $name =  'system' . ( ! empty($name) ? '.' : '') . $name;

    if (!UserHelper::hasPermission($name)) {
        App::abort(401, 'You are not authorized to access route '.$name);
    }
});
```

You can apply the filter by putting a before filter on your route, e.g.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'permissions'), function()
{
    // routes
}
```

With this system, you could create permission groups like these:

```
Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name'        => 'Super Administrators',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system' => 1,
    ),
));

Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name'        => 'Administrators',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system.users' => 1,
        'system.products' => 1,
        'system.store' => 1,
        'system.profile' => 1,
    ),
));
Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'id' => $id++,
    'name'        => 'Managers',
    'permissions' => array(
        'system.products' => 1,
        'system.store' => 1,
        'system.profile' => 1,
    ),
));
```

So if a user has the `system.products` permission, he'd be able to use every products route.

Now, for the part where you wish to show links to certain groups, you can do that with a helper like this:

```
public static function has($permission)
{
    $all = [];
    $parts = explode('.',$permission);
    $permission = '';

    foreach($parts as $part) {
        $permission .= (!empty($permission) ? '.' : '') . $part;
        $all[] = $permission;
    }

    return Sentry::check() and Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess($all);
}
```

You'd simply pass the route name (e.g. system.products) to the function and it'll return whether the user has access to it.
Source: https://laracasts.com/forum/conversation/post/2819

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool package for sentry ACL that implements a fully featured admin panel https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl